# Manifolds with $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$-action.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

What is the condition on $n$-dimensional real manifolds in order that they admit an $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$-action in the sense of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group_action that resembles the canonical $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$-action on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in each coordinate patch, i.e. locally generated by a vector field $V=A_{ij}x_j \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ with $A \in gl_n(\mathbb{R})$? Are there examples where you can "peice together" the canonical action on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to get an action on the total space?

Comment: We can always define a trivial $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ action.

Comment: What do you mean by trivial?

Comment: @kk99 For any group $G$ and set $X$ there is a trivial action $G \times X \to X$ given by $g \cdot x = x$ (for all $g \in G$, $x \in X$).

Comment: OK, let me rephrase the question.

Comment: Now I don't understand precisely what the question means. One can certainly write down plenty of $GL(n, \Bbb R)$-actions on spaces more complicated than $\Bbb R^n$---would you be content with a description of these?

Comment: Yes please, I understand the question is a little ambiguous but I am trying to understand how group actions should look in local coordinates. In particular, for a $GL_n(\mathbb{R}^n)$-action the generating vector field should "look like" $V= A_{ij}x_j \partial/\partial x_i$ where $A \in gl_n(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an arbitrary real matrix. But I assume globally this is only well-defined for certain manifolds, the first example popping into my head perhaps being affine.

Comment: Yes, where in local coordinates the generating vector fields take the form above.

Answer (score 1):

There are several non-trivial examples. For example, the general linear group $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ acts on the Grassmannians $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (even transitively). In particular it acts on projective space $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}(\mathbb{R})$. More generally, $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on flag manifolds.